Did the Hmong/Meo destroy two Japanese divisions during WW2?
I have read in the French comic "Indochine" about an historical event that I can't find on the web, so I am wondering if the author has imagined it. In the comic, an old soldier speaks to others about the Hmong (Meo in the comic,because of the French writing I suppose but internet says Meo are Hmong). He says they are brave and independent people, and quotes two examples of their fightings. I summarize what is said in the comic below:

The first one is after the invasion of Indochina by Japan, Japanese sent two divisions to submit the Hmong, but they were beaten because the Hmong used traps in the jungle and mountains
The second event is that in 1949, the Popular Army of Liberation of Mao attacked in North Indochina with a few divisions, because Mao wanted the head of the Hmong king. But they were beaten by ambushes and ultimately by a cavalry charge led by the king of the Hmong

I have doubts about the veracity of both events, but the sort of comics such as "Indochine" is often renowned as historically accurate, evenif a little fancy and exaggeration could happen. Here, it looks like both events were entirely imagined.

First event: I could not find a Japanese division, nor two, being destroyed in Northern Indochina. The events of 1940 there only shows limited Japanese losses, and against the French and not the Hmong. It is the same for the events of 1945 when the Japanese chased down French authorities
Second event: Nationalist Chinese troops fled in Northern Burma, but apparently not or few in Indochina. Also, I did not find events of Communist troops invading Northen Indochina until the war between China and Vietnam in the 60s. My understanding was that Mao's troops had good relationship because they helped Communist Vietminh against the French immediately after 1949. Also, a cavalry charge by mountain people in jungle, where I suppose that breeding was not a common activity, is doubtful

Question:

Did the Japanese attack specifically Hmong people? Did they loose two divisions in the process? Only by traps?
Did PLA attack specifically Hmong people and their king in 1949 (or before or after)? Did they loose troops on the process? Did a cavalry charge happen?


I'm not a fan of questions based on works of fiction, because there is no reason to assume any basis in historical fact. A quick search shows plenty of sources stating that the Hmong fought on both sides of these conflicts.

@BrianZ yes I found the fighting on both sides but it looked more like collaboration versus resistance and not heavy fighting destroying two divisions
About work on fiction, I understand your point but it is also worthy to know if a fact learnt through fiction is trustable or not. Think about all war movies that put wrong or correct ideas in mind of their audience. If this has been about Europe, I would not have asked because I would have considered easy to find the information if it was true. About this part of asian history, it is more difficult

It's hard to prove some alleged thing didn't happen, but this is significant enough that I'm convinced it probably didn't. If it did the evidence should not be hard to find.

Re "sent two divisions" From what I can tell from a review of available literature, this is almost certainly false. There were very few Japanese troops in the area, not exceeding a few battalions in strength. My limited understanding is that a battalion of the Imperial Japanese forces comprised around 1,000 men, while a division had about 20,000 personnel. There are no reports of any large-scale engagements between Hmong guerillas and the Japanese army that I could find.

@BrianZ I agree. Actually, I guess that enough people saying they never heard of it nor found information on it would not be a proof, but would be enough to me to say this has been imagined by the author

I tried to do some research on this, and the best I was able to come up with was this war memoir that partially covers the fighting during that period. Its fairly old, and only has one review on Amazon, so I have no idea about its quality.
